# is there any software available to directly write in mobi format?

Tags: mobi, software

is there any software in which I can directly write so that the book directly can be saved as .mobi file WYSIWYG format?

I do not like to convert the book as it takes a lot of time and testing in kindle previewer. is there any solution maybe commercial or free or opensource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question -- if I may restate -- is whether there are tools which allow you to create ebooks natively  for Kindle.

Probably not, although it does have some specialized creation tools (Kindle Textbook Creator, > Kindle Kids' Book Creator, Kindle Comic Creator, Kindle Previewer).

My guess is that only Amazon.com could create such a tool because the .mobi standard is a proprietary format and is updated fairly regularly.

Some  tools have features  which let you export  to .mobi format (from MS word, PDF, or .mobi),  that includes Calibre  https://calibre-ebook.com/ Sigil, and Adobe InDesign. usually it converts from epub to mobi -- though calibre lets you convert from MS Word to mobi. But it isn't always a good conversion.

The thing is, aside from being a binary file, the Kindle format is trying to align closely to the epub format, so it makes sense (in my opinion) to focus on developing and testing an epub file -- and then after the fact converting the epub to mobi (and testing it and maybe  the styles so it works well on kindle devices and apps).

It's crazy and a waste of time to do all this; it would be a lot easier if Amazon.com  had adopted the epub standard. Certainly that would be better for publishers. But Amazon has come half-way and said if something is a valid EPUB file, then our Kindle Previewer app can reliably convert it to mobi. That's better than nothing.

For long term use, it's best to have an epub file -- because in the future it will be easier to convert from epub than to convert from .mobi

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you need but you can use libreoffice with the writer2epub extension that create automatically the epub version and, in conjunction with kindlegen, can create the mobi version

or you can give a try a Jutoh (http://www.anthemion.co.uk/), a book creation software that generate epub and mobi

hope this can help